# Get headers from SignIn to custom axiosInstance nextAuth

Tags: next.js, jwt, next-auth, refresh-token

I have a custom back-end that generates JWT tokens and refresh tokens, using next-auth to manage sessions on the front-end.

In next-auth we have a Credentials provider that simply gets accesstoken in body and stores in session, while the refreshtoken is in the set-cookie header so we can also simply res.setHeader to the initial request to wire the whole thing up... theoretically this should work, but SignIn uses it's own axios/fetch to login, this loses the refresh token...

Sample code

```
const anonymousProvider = (request, response) =>
    CredentialsProvider({
        id: "anon",
        name: "anon",
        type: "credentials",
        async authorize(credentials, req) {
            try {
                const res = await postLogin(undefined, '/api/auth/authenticate-anonymous');
                //also set set-cookie from our server
                //if we log res.headers we will get the set-cookie
                Object.entries(res.headers).forEach((keyArr) => {
                    response.setHeader(keyArr[0], keyArr[1])
                });
                return res.data;
            } catch (error) {
                //returning null rejects the promise and shows that authentication failed
                console.log(error);
                return null;
            }
        },
    });
```

Some ideas I had

1. somehow injecting a custom axios instance to sign in so that same instance used in my API calls will have the credentials
2. on client side after signing in somehow copying the headers from this to our own customAxios instance.
3. Using my own axios instance to manually call the api/auth/login api then how to add this data to session if login successful?

Please answer any of the above way or provide any other to fix the issue...